# jquery rotate crossbrowser issues

Tags: jquery, rotation

I'm trying to rotate my div's but it's only working in firefox. How can I fix this

```
    $(this).animate({
    rotate: '+=90deg',
    '-webkit-transform': '+=90deg',
    '-ms-transform': '+=90deg',
    '-o-transform': '+=90deg',
    '-moz-transform': '+=90deg'

    }, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/), and use this CSS rule:

```
-sand-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

It supports every browser - even IE.